# iOS 7 UINavigationBar Background image hides Title view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I made iOS app, in which i want my app to compatible with iOS 7

Problem which i am facing is, when i run my app on iOS 7, Background image of my `UINavigationBar` hides my `titleview` and `back button`

[image: screenshot here]:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    self.title=@"Artist";
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];


}
```

also when, i set Background image of `UINavigationBar` to nil it shows `titleview` and `back button`

When i run my apps prior to iOS 7 it works properly.

Please help.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What is the tintColor value for you navigationBar?

Comment: `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:6.0/255.0 green:12.0/255.0 blue:19.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];`

Comment: That tint color seems dark, as does your background image. Try setting  your tint color to whiteColor and see what happens

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behavior of `tintColor` for bars has changed on iOS 7.0, please check the image below:

[image]

You can see that

`tintColor`: is the color for the interactive elements within a navigation bar including button images and titles.

`barTintColor` is the background color of the `UINavigationBar`.

For your issue: you can do the below:

```
navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:6.0/255.0 green:12.0/255.0 blue:19.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Comment: I suggest to remove all the appearance settings you have made for your navigationBar and try the defaults first.

Comment: `barTintColor` crashes on iOS 6

Comment: It will, it is only available for iOS7,  you need to check the version of iOS and use the proper attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The default font color is black so you are probably drawing a black font on a black background. Try the following:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
                              [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

check the property extend edges on the property inspector of your view this will extend the edges from the bottom of your navigation bar to the top of your screen so your background image will be at the right place

[image]

check the transition guide for ios7 if you want more info about new things in ios7
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html

Comment: Where is  extend edges on the property inspector ?

Comment: i added a screenhot . you can see the option Under top bar in the category extend edges, check this option

Comment: Yes i have checked both all four option which you have checked still not working. http://i.imgur.com/0ydD1Y8.png

Comment: then i'm not sure what the solution could be, maybe this webpage can help http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-7-update/

Comment: I have also wrote,  `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout=NO;
    }` in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

following code worked for me

In viewDidLoad

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: I am using Image on navigationBar not color.

Comment: I am using image for navigationBar as well. Those code worked for me. Best place to set the tint color will be at the time of initializing navigation bar. Suppose if you have UINavigationController *myNavController=....    myNavController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor];  ...self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor whiteColor]; overrides the color from default...