# Navigation bar buttons lost tint on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am experiencing strage issue on iOS7. The navbar just after first time user gets to main screen:
[image: Nice navbar]
The navbar after simple push/pop
[image: Bad navbar]
The setup in storyboard:
[image: Setup]
It's setup for logout button, the same is set up for search button.
There's no dealings performed with `navigationItem` in code. Any suggestions?
**EDIT** For sure i can do the trick with

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

But i don't understand the reason of losing tint. And this is the question, not what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS7 you need to set the tintColor for the navigationBar to change the buttonItems color:

```
self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Or you can set it from the storyboard as well.

For more explanation check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18822479/1262634) SO answer.